# unable to install "dplyr" package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, package

While installing the dplyr package I am getting the error in RStudio, whereas if I am trying to install the same in R, I ma getting an error saying:

> package dplyr is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

this is the error I am getting in RStudio:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL ‘bindrcpp’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
```

Comment: Have you tried to install the package 'bindrcpp' ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what version of R you are using? Just use the 
   **version**
command. If it's less than 3.5.2 you might find that libraries dplyr requires aren't being installed and that's why it's failing to find, for example, bindrcpp.

In my corporate environment I had a very similar issue trying to install dplyr after our tech support operation upgraded my PC, but installed a too-old version of R.

Comment: Ah. Then it's outside my experience level I'm afraid.